# Writing then reading in-memory bytes (BytesIO) gives a blank result

Tags: python, byte, gzip, bytesio

I wanted to try out the python BytesIO class.

As an experiment I tried writing to a zip file in memory, and then reading the bytes back out of that zip file. So instead of passing in a file-object to `gzip`, I pass in a `BytesIO` object. Here is the entire script:

```
from io import BytesIO
import gzip

# write bytes to zip file in memory
myio = BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=myio, mode='wb') as g:
    g.write(b"does it work")

# read bytes from zip file in memory
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=myio, mode='rb') as g:
    result = g.read()

print(result)
```

But it is returning an empty `bytes` object for `result`. This happens in both Python 2.7 and 3.4. What am I missing?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You need to [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) back to the beginning of the file after writing the initial in memory file...

```
myio.seek(0)
```

Comment: Buffers filled by matplotlib savefig() also do need this before they can be sent by an application server. Thanks for ending hours of research!

Comment: Or use `getvalue()`. These little things are scattered all over the place!

Comment: getvalue() didn't work for me except the seek(0)

Answer (score 6):

How about we write and read gzip content in the same context like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from io import BytesIO
import gzip

content = b"does it work"

# write bytes to zip file in memory
gzipped_content = None
with BytesIO() as myio:
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=myio, mode='wb') as g:
        g.write(content)
    gzipped_content = myio.getvalue()

print(gzipped_content)
print(content == gzip.decompress(gzipped_content))
```

Comment: I don't think `g.close()` is needed here, right?

Comment: @juan you're right. since it is in context, g.close() is not necessary. I removed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`myio.getvalue()` is an alternative to `seek` that *returns the bytes containing the entire contents of the buffer* ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue)).

It worked for me after facing a similar issue.