# How to download pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am am creating a web app with Python and Flask. My python code outputs a pandas dataframe, which I would like the user to download by the click of a button. More specifically, I want the user to click the download button and I want the csv file to be displayed as a download on the bottom download bar in Google Chrome ([Something like this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFWin.png)).

Here's what I did so far:

HTML button:

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="csvDownload()" href=""  type="button">Download</a>
```

Which leads to this JavaScript function:

```
 function csvDownload() {
        location.replace('/download')
    }
```

In Flask, I process it like so:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
   backend.final_data.to_csv()
```

Here, backend.final_data is my data frame coming from another python file called backend.

Comment: this may help you [help1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634862/use-flask-to-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-and-serve-a-download) [help2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809592/flask-pandas-creating-a-download-file) [help3](https://gist.github.com/c0ldlimit/5164171), [help4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721350/python-flask-send-file-and-variable) basically from flask side you need to return the text/csv as a file response in download folder

Comment: thanks a lot, help1 solved my problem

Comment: yes it does @sahasrara62

Comment: if solution give by @mutantkeyboard solved your problem also you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know how your `to_csv()` is written, but it should look something like:

```py
def to_csv ():
    path = "/Examples.csv"
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)
```

Notice `send_file(path, as_attachment=True)`

That way, you won't present the data to the browser, but will rather notify the browser to download the file as attachment.